# Extension function from a generic interface

Tags: kotlin, generics, extension-function

Consider the following interface

```
interface EntityConverter<in A, out B> {
    fun A.convert(): B

    fun List<A>.convert(): List<B> = this.map { it.convert() }
}
```

I want to use it in a spring boot application where specific implementations get injected so that the extension function becomes usable on the type.

However this doesn't work. The compiler does not resolve the extension function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that you're defining extension functions that are *also* member functions of the `EntityConverter` type. You should take a look at [this part of the doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#declaring-extensions-as-members) for information about how this works.

Essentially, in order to use them, you need 2 instances in scope:

- the *dispatch* receiver (an instance of `EntityConverter<A, B>`)
- the *extension* receiver (an instance of `A` or `List<A>`, where `A` matches the first type parameter of the `EntityConverter` in scope)

You can use [with()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/with.html) to bring the `EntityConverter` in scope so you can use `convert` on your other instances using the usual `.` syntax:

```kotlin
val converter = object : EntityConverter<Int, String> {
    override fun Int.convert() = "#$this"
}

val list = listOf(1, 2, 3)

val convertedList = with(converter) {
    list.convert()
}
println(convertedList) // prints [#1, #2, #3]
```

Now you have to decide whether this kind of usage pattern is what makes most sense for your use case. If you'd prefer more "classic" calls without extensions (`converter.convert(a)` returning a `B`), you can declare your functions as regular methods taking an argument instead of a receiver.

#### Bonus: functional interface

As a side note, if you add the `fun` keyword in front of your `EntityConverter` interface, you can create instances of it very easily like this:

```kotlin
val converter = EntityConverter<Int, String> { "#$this" }
```

This is because your converter interface only has a single abstract method, making it easy to implement with a single lambda. See the docs about [functional interfaces](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/fun-interfaces.html).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can mention extension functions as a part of interface, because it's like static functions.

I'd recommend to put "common" function in interface with `A` typed parameter. Then just put extension method for list nearby.

```
interface EntityConverter<in A, out B> {
    fun convert(a: A): B    
}

fun <A, B> EntityConverter<A, B>.convert(list: List<A>): List<B> = list.map { convert(it) }
```

**Update**

I wasn't aware about possibility of inheritance of extension methods in Kotlin. And about its overriding as well. So my answer could be just an alternative of using extension methods.

Comment: So you don't see a way to put the extension function on `A` / `List<A>`?

Comment: This is not quite correct. Extensions can definitely be members and are not static, they can access state from the enclosing class. This is the primary tool for context-based programming in Kotlin

Comment: @Joffrey [Documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#extensions-are-resolved-statically) says extension functions "are dispatched statically, which means they are not virtual by receiver type". I'm not sure about implementation, but they acting like they are static.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. Regular extension functions are indeed dispatched statically. However, member extensions are only dispatched statically with respect to their *extension* receiver, but virtually with respect to their *dispatch* receiver. So they can be overridden regarding their dispatch receiver. It's explained in [Declaring extensions as members](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#declaring-extensions-as-members) (please refresh because the link seems to behave oddly)